# How to install manually package for sublime text on osx?

Tags: macos, package, sublimetext

Trying to install third-party ST3-LiveReload package for Sublime text (https://github.com/Grafikart/ST3-LiveReload) on osx manually (there are no this package in package manager). When I extracting folder from the zipped archive in MacOs>Packages folder, it doesn't work for sublime cause needed to be .sublime-package extension.
Git instruction for macOs in this repository not worked for me too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry about `.sublime-package` files, these are installed when using Package Control.

The instructions on the link repository use an outdated URL. Here is how you install the package using `git`:

```
cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/Sublime\ Text\ 3/Packages/
git clone https://github.com/Grafikart/ST3-LiveReload LiveReload
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried to just clone the folder (with git command), it still didn't work - when I put folder inside the Package folder, Sublime don't see the package even after the restart. Than I just added the repository through package control - its appeared there and then installed it - so Sublime created .sublime package file.

Comment: Can you be specific about "didn't work", because it worked perfectly for me (OS X, Sublime Text Build 3118). Any errors in the console?

Comment: My bad, used not "Application Support" path before for cloning. Thank you, perfectly works.

Comment: used "/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Packages" path instead of "/Users/ /Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages"